# I might go with you to the market if I wasn't ill

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *I **might** go to the beach if the sun **was** shining.*
2. *I **might** go with you to the market if I **wasn't** ill.*
3. *I **might** do better if I **had** a different teacher.*
4. *If I **won** the lottery, I **might** buy a 20-room mansion.*

Are all of them correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Micah Windsor's answer is correct.

According to my reading, 1 and 2 *kindasorta* work, but are rare instances where the correct use of the subjunctive 'were' somewhat helps the sentences along. Also, commas.

> I might go to the beach, if the sun ***were*** shining.

> I might go with you to the market, if I ***weren't*** ill.

Apart from omitting helpful commas, I don't think there's anything wrong with 3 and 4.

To be honest, the strangest thing about these sentences is the way they are ordered. It feels much more natural to say:

> If the sun was shining, I might go to the beach.

> If I wasn't ill, I might go with you to the market.

etc.

When phrased like that, the absence of the pedantic/formal 'were' also seems entirely natural, and all four sentences 'work'.

Comment: Would you still say commas were helpful/necessary if I used "could" in place of "might" in those sentences? Here I'm not concerned about the meanings of "could" in those contexts but just commas.

Comment: Yes I would. You have two distinct sentence clauses, and I'd usually expect a comma. The way to think of it is that there is the main clause that could exist as a complete sentence on its own ("I might go to the beach"), and then there is a subclause which cannot act as a sentence on its own that modifies the main clause ("if the sun was shining").